# Sending the form to Sptari v4

Tags: reactjs, api, backend, strapi

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ywre8.jpg)Good afternoon colleagues.
my problem is that i want to understand how exactly i can get the image from Strapi if i have sent it with a form and additional fields of the input.
In the screenshots that I provided you can see my table in Strapi and also the console log in which you can see that I do not get the image =(
I can not solve the problem, i read the documentation, but i also do not understand what i'm doing wrong.
I will also give you my code where the form is sent to Strapi

```
  const [reviewData, setReviewData] = useState({
    id: id,
    title: "",
    rating: "",
    body: "",
    photo: "",
  });

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setReviewData((prevReviewData) => ({
      ...prevReviewData,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };

const handlePhotoChange = (event) => {
  const file = event.target.files[0];
  setReviewData((prevReviewData) => ({
    ...prevReviewData,
    photo: file,
  }));
  console.log(file);
};

const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("files.photo", reviewData.photo); // Обратите внимание на изменение здесь
  formData.append("data", JSON.stringify(reviewData));

  console.log(formData, "<----FORM_DATA");

   fetch("http://localhost:1337/api/reviews", {
  method: "POST",
  body: formData,
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${tokens}`,
  },
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
    // Здесь вы можете получить доступ к данным о фотографии и другим данным
    const { photo, ...restData } = data;
    console.log("Данные о фотографии:", photo);
    console.log("Остальные данные:", restData);
    
    dispatch(fetchReviews());
  })
  .catch((error) => console.error(error));

setIsOpen(false);

            <form
              className={styles.add_container__form_articles}
              onSubmit={handleSubmit}
            >
              <label>
                Заголовок
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="title"
                  value={reviewData.title}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
              </label>
              <label>
                Rating:
                <input
                  type="number"
                  name="rating"
                  value={reviewData.rating}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
              </label>
              <label>
                Body:
                <textarea
                  name="body"
                  value={reviewData.body}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
              </label>
              <label>
                Фотография:
                <input type="file" name="photo" onChange={handlePhotoChange} />
              </label>
              <button
                className={styles.add_container__publish_button}
                type="submit"
              >
                Опубликовать
              </button>
            </form>[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7rYa.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9C9j.jpg)
};
```

Tried watching this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2M3pOovhGTk + looking at the documentation

Comment: You need to `populate` relational fields, witch media is part of

Comment: @antokhio we decided to go with express and PostgreSQL. thanks for the reply 